# Where to put conditional statement when setting state in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am making a Pomodoro Clock project from [freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/front-end-libraries/front-end-libraries-projects/build-a-pomodoro-clock) using React.js. I want to change the state conditionally based on the current state. Do I need to use `this.state` or the `state` argument from the `updater` function in `setState`?

Here is my code:

Using `state` argument:

```js
this.setState(state => {
    let newState = {}
    if (state.timer === 0){
        this.beep.current.play()
        if (state.type === 'Session') {
            newState.timer = state.break * 60
            newState.type = 'Break'
        } else {
            newState.timer = state.session * 60
            newState.type = 'Session'
        }
    } else {
        newState.timer = state.timer - 1
    }
    return newState
})
```

Using `this.state`:

```js
if (this.state.timer === 0) {
    this.beep.current.play()
    if (this.state.type === 'Session') {
        this.setState(state => ({
            timer: state.break * 60,
            type: 'Break'
        }))
    } else {
        this.setState(state => ({
            timer: state.session * 60,
            type: 'Session'
        }))
    }
} else {
    this.setState(state => ({
        timer: state.timer - 1
    }))
}
```

If you need more context, you can see both codes on CodePen [using `this.state`](https://codepen.io/farishafizhan/pen/MWKQpjZ) and [without `this.state`](https://codepen.io/farishafizhan/pen/ExPQWyq). You can run the test on the upper left corner. As you can see in the CodePen that both codes pass the test. Which of those should I use and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you want to make changes to the state that depend on the previous state you should pass a function that receives the previous state as a parameter. If you use `this.state` instead, you might get some unexpected behaviour because the `setState` method is asynchronous, so you can't actually guarantee that the values stored in `this.state` will be the ones from the previous state when the state is actually updated

tldr; Use the first option you mentioned